# hoe to fix Gradle error in flutter project?

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

PS M:\login_page_official\firebase_signin\login_signin> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
e: C:/Users/ganes/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8bcc045eb4873c7d7cfabaaf6dc61958/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version
of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 59s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            181.7s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ M:\login_page_official\firebase_signin\login_signin\android\build.gradle:
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''                                                           │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

help me to clear this error

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to your `android/build.gradle` or `android/settings.gradle` file, depending on your Flutter project **creation**, and update the Kotlin version.

Make sure to view the link that was given to you by the console: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details.

Depending on when you made your Flutter project, there are 2 different answers.

### Note

You might have to try different versions of Kotlin to figure out which version works with your project. As of now, I wouldn't go any higher than `version 1.9.10` as there are known issues with versions that are higher in Flutter.

You can find out more here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/144566.

### Flutter project before version `3.16` and haven't migrated.

1. Open `android/build.gradle`.
2. Update the version.
3. Run `flutter clean`.
4. Open `Android Studio` and let it do the `gradle sync`.
5. If you have any `build_runners`, re-run them.
6. Run your build, debug, release, etc. and you shouldn't see those errors.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10' // Update version on this line!
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

### Flutter created or after version `3.16`.

1. Open `android/settings.gradle`.
2. Update the version.
3. Run `flutter clean`.
4. Open `Android Studio` and let it do the `gradle sync`.
5. If you have any `build_runners`, re-run them.
6. Run your build, debug, release, etc. and you shouldn't see those errors.

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.3.0' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.10" apply false // Update version on this line!
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.8.1" apply false
}
```

### Want to migrate?

If you need or want to migrate your Flutter gradle, follow the instructions at: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue as the question and did the Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins to the flutter project. Now when I try to build android app the following error happens.

```
[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then   │
│ update C:\Users\Sameera\AndroidStudioProjects\skypos_backoffice_mobile\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

My problem now is as per the guidelines (https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) I have removed the buildscript {} part of android/build.gredle file. So I cannot change the ext.kotlin_version as suggested. What can I do now?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

android studio-->setting->Kotlin Compiler->select Kotlin version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).